# Determine the convergence of a series with respect to $\alpha > 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a Calculus 2 exam task:

Determine the convergence of the series below with respect to $\alpha>0$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left\vert\sin\left(1\over n\right)-\frac{\cos\left(1\over n\right)} n\right\vert^\alpha$$

My TA has advised me to follow the solution of a similar task from an older exam, but I'm having problems constructing the Maclaurin series for the series in this question.

Here is the old task and its solution I was given as guidance for my original problem:

Determine the convergence of the series below with respect to $\alpha>0$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left\vert e^{\frac 2 {n^2}}-1-\frac 2 {n^2}-\frac 2{n^4}-\frac 2{n^6}\right\vert^\alpha$$

*Solution.* From the Maclaurin expansion of $e^x$ we know that for sufficiently small values of $x$, $$e^x\approx1+x+\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}6$$

The series convergence depends on the size of its terms for large $n$, in which case $\cfrac 2 {n^2}$ truly is close to $0$, therefore: $$e^{\frac 2 {n^2}}\approx 1+\frac 2{n^2}+\frac 2{n^4}+\frac 4 {3n^6}$$
i.e. $$\frac{e^{\frac 2 {n^2}}-1-\frac 2{n^2}-\frac 2{n^4}-\frac 2{n^6}}{\frac 1{n^6}}\approx-\frac 2 3\qquad(1)$$

The above observation guides us to compare the given series with the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\cfrac 1{n^{6\alpha}}$. For such comparison we evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left\vert e^{\frac 2 {n^2}}-1-\frac 2{n^2}-\frac 2{n^4}-\frac 2{n^6}\right\vert^\alpha}{\frac 1{n^{6\alpha}}}=\left\vert\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{\frac 2 {n^2}}-1-\frac 2{n^2}-\frac 2{n^4}-\frac 2{n^6}}{\frac 1{n^{6}}}\right\vert^\alpha\qquad(2)$$

By substituting $x=\cfrac 2 {n^2}$, the limit will equal
$$\left\vert\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x-\frac {x^2}2 -\frac{x^3}4}{\frac{x^3}8}\right\vert^\alpha,$$
under the condition that the limit under the absolute value exists. We notice that for that limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x-\frac {x^2}2 -\frac{x^3}4}{\frac{x^3}8}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x-\frac {3x^2}4}{\frac {3x^2}8}$$$$\stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-\frac {3x}2}{\frac{3x}4}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-\frac 3 2}{\frac 3 4}=-\frac 2 3$$

We were expecting such result due to the approximation $(1)$. We conclude that the limit $(2)$ equals $\left(\frac 2 3\right)^\alpha\in\langle 0,+\infty\rangle$, therefore by the limit comparison test, the given series converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\cfrac 1 {n^{6\alpha}}$ converges, i.e. if and only if $6\alpha>1$, i.e. $$\alpha>\frac 1 6$$

Thanks in advance for any hints on the subject.

Comment: Regarding the approximation $(1)$ - we're not allowed to use calculators on our exams; I'm not sure how we approximated this result either.

Answer (score 1):

We have that by

- $\sin x=x-\frac16 x^3+O(x^5)$
- $\cos x=1-\frac12 x^2+O(x^4)$

we obtain

$$\sin\left(1\over n\right)-\frac{\cos\left(1\over n\right)} n = \frac 1n-\frac16\frac1{n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)- \frac 1n+\frac12\frac1{n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)=\frac13\frac1{n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)$$

which leads to $\alpha>\frac13$.

---

**Edit**

As an alternative, to avoid the big-O notation, it suffices to show that

$$\frac{\sin\left(1\over n\right)-\frac{\cos\left(1\over n\right)} n}{\frac13\frac1{n^3}} \to 1$$

and then conclude by limit comparison test that we need $\alpha>\frac13$ for convergence.

Comment: @Bernard Oh yes of course! Thanks I fix it.

Comment: Also, personally; I would use  Taylor-Young's formula, with $\Bigl(\dfrac1{n^3}\Bigr)$ as a complementary term.

Comment: @Bernard My idea here is refer to limit comparison to conlcude. What do you mean with "as a complementary term"?

Comment: What remains when you've subtracted the expansion at a certain order. You use $O\Bigl(\dfrac1{n^5}$, and I prefer to use` little o`, as it yields directly an asymptotic equivalent. But this depends on how you're familiar with asymptotic analysis.

Comment: @Bernard Ah ok, yes I also often use little-0 notation, there is not a particular reason for which I've adopted big-O notation here.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however, the O notations aren't part of my Calculus 2, so I don't really understand your work. Is there any way this particular task can be solved without the use of the O notation? Or can it be explained in a fairly simple manner so that I could read your solution better?

Comment: @kyrillox Yes, I add an alternative way.